Online PowerBi designer tool bar on is disabled
Online PowerBi designer tool bar is disabled as shown in the` screenshot, like Open data model and Refresh features are disabled. Don't know what's wrong with it.
I have Power BI Pro license as I have Office 365 E5 subscription, don't know it is because of license subcription.


What roles have you been assigned on the workspace and report?
